# Navigation from non-master-detail page to master-detail page (MVVMCROSS)

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, mvvmcross

I have Login -> Lobby -> (Master/Detail pages).

The Lobby is the main page that I need one instance only, where you can as well access some of the details pages from it. The Lobby it self is a content page that is not a detail page of any master page.

The problem I have is that once I navigate to the a master-detail page I lose the Lobby from the navigation stack, so once I press the back button on the Android tablet it is as if I have clicked the Home button. I want the Lobby page to remain on the root of the stack.

I have tried initializing the Lobby from the MasterPageViewModel however this caused a problem of opening an initial empty master/detail page.

Kindly advise.

Comment: In the `OnBackPressed` method of the native android-activity, you will have to check if the navigation stack is empty or not and on that basis navigate to your lobby page!!

Comment: How do you navigate from Login page to to your MasterDetail page?

Comment: I think you can set Lobby as RootPage in `App.xaml.cs` .

Comment: Thank you for you reply guys. However the issue is that I am using MVVMCross which is handling the navigation stuff.

Comment: There's several things you can do, one is to just do a navigator delete the login page once the user has logged in, so that pressing the back button goes to the dashboard as is expected. Another is to simply override the back button functionality